# SockJS pass Auth header

Tags: angular, spring, sockjs

I am trying to open a connection in SocketJs with a passing auth header, but it's not works it gives 401 .

here is my code

```html
  const ws = new SockJS(WebSocketBaseUrl, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.token}`
    }
  });

  this.stompClientSubscribeUser = Stomp.Stomp.over(ws);

  const _this = this;

  _this.stompClientSubscribeUser.connect({
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${_this.token}`
    }
  },
    function () {
      _this.stompClientSubscribeUser.subscribe('/user/' + _this.userId + '/queue/messages', function (sdkEvent: any) {
        _this.onMessageReceived(sdkEvent);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

SocketJs doesn't support authorization tokens, please refer to

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node#authorisation

and related ticket on SocketJS-client: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/196

Another thing to note - options should be the 3rd argument:

```
var sockjs = new SockJS(url, _reserved, options);
```